# Convertir una variable en array

Tags: php

Estoy necesitando convertir una variable en un array, pero no doy con la clave.
Espero explicarme bien. Desde un select multiple recibo una variable que trae por ejemplo el texto **adminUser archivos banner** separadas por un espacio en blanco. A través de un foreach intento extraer  los resultados para convertirlos en un único array como en este ejemplo válido:

```
    array(3) { [0]=> string(11) "./adminUser" [1]=> string(10) "./archivos" [2]=> string(8) "./banner" }
```

El foreach es este

```
    foreach ($directorioSelect as $excluidos) { $exclude_dir = array (preg_split("/ /", $excluidos)); }
```

Pero me arroja:

```
    array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "adminUser" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "archivos" } } array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "banner" } }
```

Lo estoy intentando con

```
    explode(" ", $excluidos); y str_split($excluidos);
```

Podéis ayudarme y dar una explicación lógica de que hago mal?. Gracias de antemano!!!

```
if (!$_POST) {
  echo '<form action="" method="post">
        Seleccionar directorios a excluir:<br>
        <select multiple name="directorio[]" style="width:300px; height:200px; margin-top:10px;" required>';
    // Primero lista directorios
    $base = opendir("."); // Ruta base
    while ($directorio = readdir($base)) {
        if (is_dir($directorio)) {
            if ($directorio!= "." && $directorio!= ".." && $directorio!= "backup") {
      echo '<option value="'. $directorio . '">'. $directorio . '</option>';
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($base);
  echo '</select><br>
        <input type="submit" style="margin-top:10px;" value="Aceptar">
        </form>';
} else {
    $directorioSelect = $_POST["directorio"];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($directorioSelect); $i++) {
    //echo "<b>" . $i . ":</b> " . $directorioSelect[$i] . "<br>"; // Imprime directorios a excluir seleccionados
}

$exclude_dir = [];
foreach ($directorioSelect as $excluidos) {
    // Combina el anterior con el resultado de cada iteración
    
    $exclude_dir = array_unique($exclude_dir);

    $backup_files = '.'; // Ruta base
    $backup_file_name = './backup/backups/copia de seguridad ' . date ("d-m-Y H-i") . '.zip'; // Ruta donde se crea el zip
    $download_file = false; // True descarga el archivo una vez creado

    if (!touch($backup_file_name)) {
    echo "<script>alert('Permiso denegado en $backup_file_name')</script>";
    exit();
    }
}

class FlxZipArchive extends ZipArchive {

    public function addDir($location, $name) {
        $this->addEmptyDir($name);
        $this->addDirDo($location, $name);
    }

    private function exclude($location) {
        global $exclude_dir;
        for($n = 0; $n < count($exclude_dir); $n++) {
            if (strpos($location, $exclude_dir[$n]) === 0) {
            return TRUE;
            }
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    private function addDirDo($location, $name) {
        global $exclude_dir;
        $name .= '/';
        $location .= '/';

        $dir = opendir ($location);
        while ($file = readdir($dir)) {
            if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
                continue;
            }

            if ($this->exclude($location.$file)) {
                continue;
            }

            $do = (filetype( $location . $file) == 'dir') ? 'addDir' : 'addFile';
            $this->$do($location . $file, $name . $file);
        }
    }
}

$za = new FlxZipArchive;
$res = $za->open($backup_file_name, ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($res === TRUE) {
    $za->addDir($backup_files, basename($backup_files));
    $za->close();
} else {
echo "<script>alert('No se ha creado la copia')</script>";
}

if ($download_file) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($backup_file_name) . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($backup_file_name));
    readfile($backup_file_name);
    exit;
}
echo "<script>alert('Copia de seguridad de los archivos web, realizada correctamente')</script>";
echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=" . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] . "#copia\">"; // Refresca la misma url
}
```

Comment: Por qué no envías desde el `select` múltiple los valores en un `array`, simplemente es agregar `[]` al final del atributo `name`. Tal que `name="nombreDelCampo[]"`. O estoy interpretando mal tu pregunta?

Comment: Coloca un ejemplo del <select> o del payload de la petición.

Comment: @DjCrazy acabo de actualizar la pregunta con el form, así es como se envia.

Comment: Por favor agrega el resultado de `var_dump($_POST['directorio']);` aunque no creo que ese sea el problema, tal vez el _foreach_ debería estar dentro del _else_, sin ver más código será difícil averiguar.

Comment: Acabo de editar colocando el código de test al completo por si te puedes guiar. var_dump($_POST['directorio']);  parece ser correcto: array(3) { [0]=> string(9) "adminUser" [1]=> string(8) "archivos" [2]=> string(6) "banner" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te sobra `array (` en `$exclude_dir = array (preg_split("/ /", $excluidos));` porque la función te va a devolver un arreglo; además, no es recomendable usar *preg_split* cuando *explode* es suficiente, porque el primero es para expresiones regulares y no son necesarias en este caso.

```
$directorioSelect = [
    './dir1 ./dir2 ./dir3',
    './dir4 ./dir5 ./dir6',
    './dir7 ./dir8 ./dir9',
];

foreach ($directorioSelect as $excluidos) {
    $exclude_dir = explode(' ', $excluidos));
}
```

Resultados:

```
Primera iteración: array('./dir1', './dir2', './dir3')
Segunda iteración: array('./dir4', './dir5', './dir6')
Tercera iteración: array('./dir7', './dir8', './dir9')
```

### Opción 2 - Todo en el mismo arreglo

En caso de que los necesites todos juntos y sin que se repitan:

```
// Primero define el arreglo
$exclude_dir = [];
foreach ($directorioSelect as $excluidos) {
    // Combina el anterior con el resultado de cada iteración
    $exclude_dir = array_merge($exclude_dir, explode(' ', $excluidos));
}
// Eliminar repetidos, si los hay
$exclude_dir = array_unique($exclude_dir);
```

Resultado:

```
array('./dir1', './dir2', './dir3', './dir4', './dir5', './dir6', './dir7', './dir8', './dir9')
```

[image: Resultado en imagen]

Comment: Gracias por responder, interesante tu explicación pero si hago var_dump($exclude_dir); el resultado es array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "adminUser" } array(2) { [0]=> string(9) "adminUser" [1]=> string(8) "archivos" } array(3) { [0]=> string(9) "adminUser" [1]=> string(8) "archivos" [2]=> string(6) "banner" }... no estén todos en el mismo array, sabes porqué?

Comment: Creo que estás usando la primera opción, con la segunda están todos ahí. Voy a editar la respuesta por si no quieres que se repitan.

Comment: Listo, revisa la actualización

Comment: Algo no estoy haciendo bien, he editado la pregunta para añadir el formulario, me sigue dando los mismos resultados con tu opción 2

Comment: funciona perfecto con tu actualización, fué fallo mio al implementarla. Gracias mil!!!